# Oauth 2: Spring Boot 2: Auth Server /oauth/check_token returns user_name as null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have implemented 2 distinct servers: auth server and a resource server using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 version Greenwich.RELEASE

I am able to successfully get an access_token from auth server, use it to access protected api on resource server.

However I am not able to get user_name in the response returned by auth server's /oauth/check_token endpoint I can confirm that user_name is present in user table.

```
curl http://localhost:5000/oauth/check_token?token=a3ee84ee-6d3a-4a8f-af19-5446b55c637f | jq .
```

returns following:

```
  {
    "aud": [
      "article"
    ],
    "user_name": null,
    "scope": [
      "READ",
      "WRITE",
      "UPDATE",
      "DELETE"
    ],
    "active": true,
    "exp": 1563849438,
    "authorities": [
      "ROLE_administrator",
      "create_article",
      "read_article",
      "delete_article",
      "update_article"
    ],
    "client_id": "myclient"
  }
```

**AuthorizationServerConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            DataSource dataSource,
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    TokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
      //  security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
        security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(jdbcTokenStore());
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        //TODO JWT
        // endpoints.accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/version").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
        optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username or password wrong"));

        UserDetails userDetails = new AuthUserDetail(optionalUser.get());
        new AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker().check(userDetails);
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

**Main application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**AuthUserDetail**

```
package com.myapplication.models;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class AuthUserDetail extends User implements UserDetails {

    public AuthUserDetail(User user) {
        super(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

        getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
            role.getPermissions().forEach(permission -> {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getName()));
            });

        });
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return super.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return super.isAccountNonExpired();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return super.isAccountNonLocked();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return super.isCredentialsNonExpired();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return super.isEnabled();
    }
}
```

**User**

```
package com.myapplication.models;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User {
    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getUserName();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.enabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.accountNonExpired = user.isAccountNonExpired();
        this.credentialsNonExpired = user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        this.accountNonLocked = user.isAccountNonLocked();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(name = "account_non_expired")
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "credentials_non_expired")
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "account_non_locked")
    private boolean accountNonLocked;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

**user table ddl**

```
create table if not exists user
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_name varchar(100) not null,
    password varchar(1024) not null,
    email varchar(1024) not null,
    enabled tinyint not null,
    account_non_expired tinyint not null,
    credentials_non_expired tinyint not null,
    account_non_locked tinyint not null,
    constraint user_name
        unique (user_name)
);
```

Comment: @dur now that you asked this question, I am wondering if it has anything to do with DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter or DefaultAccessTokenConverter - maybe I need to provide my own implementation to enrich user object?

Comment: @dur It is my own package - com.myapplication.models package is where User class is. Also AuthUserDetail is also in the same package - com.myapplication.models

Comment: Is this happening because I changed user table - column names (contain underscore) are different than what default user table is expected to be?

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint at `return userDetails` and check if the username is set?

Comment: @dur I don't hit the breakpoint at that line in UserDetailsServiceImpl when I run ```curl -u myclient:secret -X POST localhost:5000/oauth/check_token\?token=a8e194a7-cd0d-4e02-8abf-8077a689d618 | jq .```

Comment: @dur I also put breakpoint at line: OAuth2Authentication result = tokenStore.readAuthentication(accessToken); in org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices loadAuthentication method. The result object has userAuthentication (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken type).principal ==> this is also all null

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem after I modified column names of my user table from camelCase to underscore_case.

To resolve this I made sure the user, permission and role class is implementing Serializable class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
----
----
}
```

and also remove the following spring jpa property if added

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. But i didn't removed `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` property

Comment: Thank you helped me save my time I spent one day in this. Thanks again.

Comment: I am using mongodb for that it also worked